# How to add Fading effect to JSliderNews 2.0 (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to find Fading effect to [JSliderNews 2.0](http://www.landofcoder.com/demo/jquery/lofslidernews/index3.html) but i am not sure how to do it tried but it didn't work

```
$(document).ready( function(){  
    var buttons = { previous:$('#jslidernews2 .button-previous') ,
                        next:$('#jslidernews2 .button-next') };          
    $('#jslidernews2').lofJSidernews({
        interval:5000,
        effect: 'fade', //easing:'easeInOutQuad',
        duration:1200,
        auto:true,
        mainWidth:590,
        mainHeight:300,
        navigatorHeight: 76,
        navigatorWidth: 160,
        maxItemDisplay:4,
        buttons:buttons } );                        
    });
```

I made minor changes to the default code but still doesn't work i added `effect & removed easing`  part which doesnt make any difference

```
effect: 'fade',
//easing:'easeInOutQuad',
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these options

```
direction       : 'opacity',
easing          : 'linear',
```